# Bash, use export and run export in single script

Tags: linux, bash, unix

```
#!/bin/bash
export foo='script...'

bash --program=foo
```

how do you run the exported "foo"
i've been working with gtkdialog and it is written

```
#!/bin/bash
export MAIN_DIALOG='...xml code...'

gtkdialog --program=MAIN_DIALOG
```

the same should be possible with a simple bash script?
i would like this to reduce the number of files i must include
currently each set of bash scripts i write for one program are saved in separate files then executed by the main script.

Comment: If the program is in the current working directory then it's judt `./$foo`

Comment: `gtkdialog --program="${MAIN_DIALOG}"` ought to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you are just looking for:

```
bash -c "$foo"
```

Answer (score 0):

To reduce the number of files, you can change the commands from separate scripts to functions in the main script:

```
cmd() {
  # actions for foo command
}
```

Then, instead of using `bash -c` to run them, you can use `eval`:

```
foo='cmd ...'

eval "$foo"
```